# Read channel values from digital potentiometer using arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm doing some basic arduino projects, and I have followed the project listed here: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SPIDigitalPot.

The project essentially shows you how to set the values for the various channels on the digital potentiometer AD5206.

Using that example as a starting point, is there a way to read the current values that are set in each of the AD5206 channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read directly from the AD5206 but if you really wanted to you could run a wire from the output pins on the AD5206 to your arduinos analog pins and read it that way.

Off the top of my head it would look something like this:

```
int potValue = ( analogRead(analogPin) / 1023 ) * 255; // divide analog pin value by 1023 to find fractional value then multiplied by 255 for pots value
```

that may not be 100% accurate but it should be within +/- 1